# Web based tool to explore how different machine learning models perform on my dataset

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I'm new to machine learning and want to try a few models on my dataset. I'm looking for a web based tool where I can upload my data (in my case images), select a pre-trained model and then view its performance. Next, I want to retrain the model on my own data or play around with certain parameters. Then I might want to upload other/own models and view its performance. Does anybody know something that could help me with this? For me, it's quite tedious to set up all the different machine learning models on my machine. There are a lot of ML papers that don't provide a proper implementation with a nice setup README. There are issues with different python versions, GPUs and so on. If I just want to play around a bit, this feels like an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go cloud with [Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/).

If you are a student you might have free credits. SageMaker allow you to see if the pattern of your ML is convergent or divergent and alert you if your ML is bringing you no where and stop the calculation.